# If file name equals the user input variable then open that file

Tags: vba, excel

**The Code:**

```
mNummer = InputBox("Please typ a number")
 If mNummer = "" 
Then MsgBox ("Makro wont function!")
 Exit Sub 
End If

Year= InputBox("Select Year", Worksheets("Vorgaben").Range("B14").Value)
 If Year= "" 
Then 
MsgBox("Makro wird abgebrochen!") 
Exit Sub 
End If

 Welle = InputBox("Bitte Welle auswählen", , "0" & Worksheets("Vorgaben").Range("B15"))
 If Welle = "" Then MsgBox ("Makro wird abgebrochen!") 
Exit Sub 
End If

 'Combine the variables in mNummerGanz '
mNummerGanz = mNummer & "_" & Year& "_" & Welle   
Worksheets("Eingabefeld").Range("F2").Value =mNummerGanz
```

The Question:

So here i combined 3 variables, which are asking for user Inputs with 3 messageboxes. Now the combined Version of it is in variable "mNummerGanz".

Now I would like to open any Excel file by going to any Directory and selecting it. But my macro should check if the Name of the selected Excel file is equals "mNummerGanz.xls". If yes, the file should be opened, if it is not equal to "mNummerGanz.xls" then it should print "error".

Does anyone have Suggestion for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you're building a string which you then want to test to see if it's a valid file name, and if so, open it?

In which case, this snippet should do that for you

```
If Len(Dir(outputpath & mNummerGanz)) <> 0 Then
    Workbooks.Open (outputpath & mNummerGanz)
Else
    MsgBox ("That file does not exist")
End If
```

It checks to see if the file exists (outputpath = folder location)
and if so, opens it.

Answer (score 0):

I can help! Also in German :)  Ich kann dir auf Deutsch helfen :)

```
 mNummer = InputBox("Please typ a number") 
    If mNummer = "" Then 
        MsgBox ("Makro wont function!") 
        Exit Sub 
    End If

Year= InputBox("Select Year", Worksheets("Vorgaben").Range("B14").Value) 
If Year= "" Then 
    MsgBox("Makro wird abgebrochen!") 
    Exit Sub 
End If

Welle = InputBox("Bitte Welle auswählen", , "0" & 

Worksheets("Vorgaben").Range("B15").Value 
If Welle = "" Then 
    MsgBox ("Makro wird abgebrochen!") 
    Exit Sub 
End If

'Combine the variables in mNummerGanz ' 
mNummerGanz = mNummer & "" & Year& "" & Welle
Worksheets("Eingabefeld").Range("F2").Value =mNummerGanz
```

**ANSWER:**

```
'typical excel variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim myPath As String
Dim myFile As String
Dim myExtension As String
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'Retrieve Target FilePath From User
  Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With FldrPicker
      .Title = "Select A Target File"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
  myPath = myPath
  If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
  myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
  myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)



'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  If myFile = "mNummerGanz.xls"
    Debug.Print "myFile = " & myFile
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook

      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

        'Do your stuff here, man.
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            'add in your string manipulation / cell dumping here
            'with a few lines


        End With


      'Close opened *.xls, save
      wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Else
        GoTo ResetSettings
  End If


ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Wow! that does it , Vielen Dank!

Comment: Dankeschön, nachstes mal werde ich nur Deutsch antworten!!